# jQuery Mobile default tab

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to set a default tab in jQuery Mobile.

My source code:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#one" id="tabId1" data-ajax="false">one</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">two</a></li>
      <li><a href="ajax-content.html" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

$("#tabs").tabs({ active: 0 });
```

It worked but has no background color, because the first tab is not actually clicked.

I want to set default tab with background when I login in.

[No background color demo](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tabs/)

Answer (score 4):

To set the active tab, try:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs("option", "active", 1);
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c29gd4h6/)**

UPDATE: the blue background on the tab button comes from the class ui-btn-active. Either add this class to the button, or instead of setting the active tab, trigger the click event on the appropriate button: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c29gd4h6/1/

Comment: i know it's default on tab two but no background blue color,if u click any tab u will see

Comment: i want set default tab and head with background color just like u click the tab

Comment: You could either trigger the click on the button: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c29gd4h6/1/ or add the ui-btn-active class: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/c29gd4h6/2/

Answer (score 1):

I have added class="ui-btn-active" in first tab-li

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="a.html" class="ui-btn-active">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.html">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
```

If not work then try below It working for me when page load only I mean refresh page in browser

Put following code in jquerymobile `pagecreate` event that will make every first tab selected

```
$('[data-role="tabs"] a:first').each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
```

I had put above lines into pagecreate event

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#homepage", function(event) {        
    $('[data-role="tabs"] a:first').each(function() {
      $(this).click();
    });
 });
```

In above line `#homepage` is my page id and `pagecreate` is event of jquery-mobile that fire when page [load/init](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
 <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one" id="tab-one" data-ajax="false">Default</a></li>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).on("pagecreate", function (event) {

            $('#tab-one').trigger('click');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the existing mentioned solutions had issues:

- the one by @ezanker showed the content but didn't set the tab button as active
- the one by @Devendra Chhaiya clicked any first link that the tab content contained also!  :-)
- I also found that the tab wasn't remaining selected when coming back to that page, so I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752704/tab-active-state-in-jquery-mobile/23725612#23725612) to fix that too.
- there was also an issue with pages loading into tab content, so I had to [fix that too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837304/jquery-ui-non-ajax-tab-loading-whole-website-into-itself/17384908#17384908)
- in addition (yes, there's more :-) I wanted to selected a *specific* tab based on the requirements of that specific page, so I added a class `select-this-tab` on page generation from the server.

So I modified the one by @Devendra Chhaiya to click *only* the actual tab *button* (and not any tab content, keep the tab selected, and also prevent content loading into the tab area.  I had to move the trigger from `pagecreate` to `pageinit` for it to work:

```
/*
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837304/jquery-ui-non-ajax-tab-loading-whole-website-into-itself/17384908#17384908
 */
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('base').remove();
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
});

$(document).on('pageinit', function () {

    console.log('pageinit');

    /*
    * Ensure the correct tab of a set is selected (and only once)
    * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336233/jquery-mobile-default-tab/64080164#64080164
    */
    $('[data-role="tabs"] [data-role="navbar"] ul li.select-this-tab').each(function () {
        console.log('Clicking tab');
        $(this).removeClass("select-this-tab").find("a").click();
    });

    /*
     * Ensure a tab REMAINS selected when coming back to that page.
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752704/tab-active-state-in-jquery-mobile/23725612#23725612
     */
    $('div[data-role="tabs"] [data-role="navbar"] a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div[data-role="tabs"] [data-role="navbar"] .ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
        $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');
    });
```

You can remove the `console.log` lines which you can just use to prove the code actually fires.